# How can I run CS:GO in 4:3 aspect ratio?

Tags: pc, counter-strike-global-offensive, graphics-card

Id prefer to play CS:GO in 4:3, with black bars down the sides.

I have an Intel Graphics card. I tried to set my graphics back to "maintain aspect ratio" but it doesnt work.

I use 4:3 800x600 in game, and 1280x720 on my desktop.

Does anyone know the answer to my problem?

Comment: @dly the title said "Intel graphic card" though

Comment: @antimo oops.. in that case I'm not even sure the game runs on it at all.

Comment: Is the problem that the picture is stretched so that the black bars aren't there?

Comment: Your question has already been answered [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/245618/how-do-i-get-the-vertical-black-bars-while-playing-cs-1-6).

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an issue related to the game itself, but the graphics driver settings.
I suggest you try downloading the latest version of the Intel graphics driver/control panel suite and installing it.

I've read about similar issues being reported by users of various Intel GPU models, and some of the users were able to resolve it by updating the driver suite.